# Relate text to Id once selected from text box with suggestion option in rcp

Tags: swt, jface, rcp

I currently have a text box that can predict String as typed.I used the [snippet](http://krishnanmohan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/eclipse-rcp-autocompletecombotext-control/) here .

There are two seprate questions

Q1)In the snippet the suggestion are passed as item but I want to relate the String to an id to update the database. If I just pass the string to snippet I need to do another query to again retrieve the id which costs resources is there a way to pass objects to the auto suggestion which will select the id of whichever name is chosen from the suggestions.

Q2)Also I dont want user to be adding new values so is there a way to force user to chose one of the values from the suggestion for the text box and not add his own values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a workaround for your Q1.

In the auto-complete shell , use a SWT Table instead of combo widget.Have two columns in the table for string and string Id.Hide the second column so that the user cannot see it.You can use this column to retrieve the ids of corresponding strings.

Or simply store the string and string ids in a hash map and give the key values set of this hash map to the combo items.